# Whole word selection keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde

I'm using KDE and I know I can double-click any word anywhere to select it, but I'm wondering if I could set up a keyboard shortcut with this functionality in Settings->Shortcuts (I don't know what to call in a custom entry).

PS: I would like to do this in the middle of the word, not in the beginning nor the end...

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

1. Ctrl + Left arrow (to go to the beginning of the word)
2. Ctrl + Shift + Right arrow. (to select the word)

Comment: Hum, I knew that. I forgot to state I want the cursor to be anywhere in the word, as in the middle...

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution can be to check if the option *Preferences* → *Keyboard* → *Layout* → *Options* → *[Switching to another Layout]* → *[Ctr+Shift]* is checked.

I've unchecked this option and I was able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right or Left Arrow</kbd> for word selection in Linux Mint 19.2.

I hope it works in Ubuntu, too.

Comment: The option is unchecked, but the command you mention works from the position of the caret... I was looking for a shortcut that would simulate the double-click.
Right now, the way to do it is to move to either the start or end of the word then select it as you described